# Using Twitter API in Python without the use of a third party authorization client

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter

I have previously used the `OAuth1` class from the `requests_oauthlib` module to authorize my request to Twitter by passing my `consumer key` and `consumer secret` key as parameters to `OAuth1` and creating an object.

However, I was wondering how I could do the same thing and add my keys to my endpoint without the use of the `requests_oauthlib` module or some other third party module. This is what I tried doing to build my endpoint:

```
url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=" + handle + "&count=" + str(count) + '&consumerkey=' + consumer_key + '&consumersecret=' + consumer_secret
```

However, it seems that `consumerkey` and `consumersecret` are not valid parameters. How can I add my keys as parameters to my endpoint directly without using an authorization client in Python?

Comment: What's the motivation for not using a library to handle the Oauth? It's required in order to access the twitter api for most of the interesting endpoints

Comment: the [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only) explain that bearer tokens are cannot be used for `/statuses` as they are to be used by apps that have not concept of “current user.”

Comment: r@Ereli Just plain curiosity of how things would work without using an external OAuth client.

Comment: If you'd like see how oauth is done, have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/24121216/1265980